# Python BeautifulSoup web scraping return none

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.facilitron.com/searchfacility/u:facilitron/lat:37.8271784/lng:-122.2913078/dist:20/activities:-1/types:-1/namelike:grass%20field'

source = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(source.content, 'lxml')

find = soup.find('div', class_="search-results-body")
print(find)
```

I am trying to get the img, title, and location of the giving website, but BeautifulSoup couldn't get the element inside of the div with the class "search-results-body" when I try to find the div with the class inside of this div, it return none.

Comment: The page loads the content via javascript.

Comment: How can I get the content that is load via javascript?

Comment: You use Selenium or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

try to change your parser to this

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(source.content, 'html.parser')
```

Comment: same result as 'lxml'

Answer (score 1):

The content you look for is highly dynamic and not present in page source (Ctrl + U). However, issuing post http requests with appropriate parameters, you can grab them out of some json response. I've parsed only the name and address of each lead. You can find lots of other information connected to each lead from the response.

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.facilitron.com/api/search/facilities/facilitron'

payload = {
    'search_option[startLoc][]': ['-122.2913078','37.8271784'],
    'search_option[distance]': '20',
    'search_option[activities][]': '-1',
    'search_option[start_row]': '0',
    'search_option[limit]': '15',
    'search_option[types][]': '-1',
    'search_option[namelike]': 'grass field'
}

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36',
    'Referer': 'https://www.facilitron.com/searchfacility/u:facilitron/lat:37.8271784/lng:-122.2913078/dist:20/activities:-1/types:-1/namelike:grass%20field'
}

res = requests.post(url,data=payload,headers=headers)
for item in res.json()['facilities']:
    print(item['name'],item['address'])
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
find = soup.find('div', {'class': 'clearfix'})
```

Comment: I did, same result

Comment: you were putting the id name instead of the class name, i have updated the answer, try now. I tested it

Comment: that is the wrong content, what I want is inside 'clearfix facility-row' and BeautifulSoup return none

Comment: so just change the name to class you want, i have shown you the syntax

Comment: I did change to the class I want and it returns none

Comment: @jedimasterbot, it does not work since, as mentioned in the comments, the content is written by Javascript.